# Shift second right y-axis label and ticks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels, ticks

I would like to shift the second right y-axis label to the right along with the ticks so it does not interfere with the first right y-axis label and ticks. Here is the code and its output:

```
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
   ymin=0, ymax=2.75,
  xmin=20, xmax=41,
  grid,
  xtick={20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40},
  ytick={0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5},
  axis y line*=left, % the '*' avoids arrow heads
 xlabel={$t$ [s]},
 xlabel near ticks,
ylabel={$v_{fuente}$ [V]},
ylabel near ticks,
width=\textwidth, 
height=0.7\textwidth,   
    ]
    
    \addplot[teal] table[x=t, y=v_DC,col sep=semicolon]{torque_de_desprendimiento.csv};
    
  \end{axis}
  
  \begin{axis}[
ymin=0, ymax=1.375,
  xmin=20, xmax=41,
  ytick={0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25},
    hide x axis,
    axis y line*=right,
    ylabel={$i_a$ [A]},
    ylabel near ticks,
width=\textwidth, 
height=0.7\textwidth,    
    ]
    
    \addplot[orange] table[x=t, y=i_DC,col sep=semicolon]{torque_de_desprendimiento.csv};
    
  \end{axis}
  
  \begin{axis}[
ymin=0, ymax=137.5,
  xmin=20, xmax=41,
  ytick={0,25,50,75,100,125},
    hide x axis,
    axis y line*=right,
    ylabel={$\theta _m$ [grados]},
    ylabel near ticks,
width=\textwidth, 
height=0.7\textwidth,    
    ]
    
    \addplot[ultra thick,violet!17] table[x=t, y=pos_DCPM,col sep=semicolon]{torque_de_desprendimiento.csv};
    
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Torque de fricción de la parte de la cadena de transmisión factible de ser rotada en los dos sentidos}
    \label{fig:torque_de_desprendimiento}
\end{figure} \FloatBarrier
```

[image: Output]

If you find a better way to do this without the use of a third dimension, it is welcome.

Here is the data I used in my code:

[.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1boHF-m9buXBfOAFfcWlrYICv8rmxe0qP/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not possible to access to your .csv file. You need share it. And **very** important: post a compilable code from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62291/can-i-draw-figure-3-y-axis-using-pgfplot can help?

Comment: Thank you @Rmano! It was helpful!